# subcribing to 2 topics and publishing selected data in same node

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone. i have two messages publishing on their message with their topic name. now i want to subscribe these two topics and publish a new topic which will take some selected data from one topic and selected data from other, then publish the new message. i can subscribe to a topics, assign some new values and publish the new message but i am unable to do the above problem.

1. Is it possible?
2. if yes, then let's take `geometry_msgs`. `Topic1` gives `Point` and `Topic2` gives `Point and Twist`. how can i create a `new geometry_msg` that subscribe to both and produce a new message such that `Point is from topic1` and `Twist is from topic2`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335240/subcribing-to-2-topics-and-publishing-selected-data-in-same-node/) by [roboter](https://answers.ros.org/users/46971/roboter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look into message filters (http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) you can create a subscriber that has its callback triggered when you have information from the 2 topics available.

In the callback you can combine that information and publish to your new topic

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roboter](https://answers.ros.org/users/46971/roboter/) on 2019-10-12**:
things are little unclear for me. Can you look t the code and show me ho to do this???

```
def listener():
    rospy.init_node('move_turtlebot', anonymous=True)  #node
    rospy.Subscriber("/Topic1", Pose, move_turtlebot)  #subcribin to topic1
    rospy.Subscriber("/Topic2", Pose, move_turtlebot)  #subscribing to topic2
    rospy.spin()

 

def move_turtlebot(data):
    pub = rospy.Publisher('Topic3', Pose, queue_size=10)                       
    move_turtlebot= Pose()    #msg type pose
    Pose.position= Topic1.Pose.postion       #take position from topic 1
    Pose.Orientation= Topic2.Pose.orientation    #take orientation from topic2

    pub.publish(data)                             #publish the msg
    rospy.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        listener()

    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-10-14**:
Please read the documentation for the package.